# No suitable constructor exists to convert from const char to "custom string", though I have created one

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, syntax-error, constructor-overloading

I am doing a custom string class in C++. However, when I debugged my code, the system said that:

> Error E0415:no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char" to "string"

Here is my header file where my custom string class is defined:

```
#ifndef _STRING
#define _STRING
#include <iostream>

class string {
private:
    char* s = nullptr;
    unsigned int size = 0;

public:
    string();
    ~string() { delete s; };
    void operator=(const char*);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, string&);
};
#endif

string::string()
    : s{ nullptr }
{
    s = new char[1];
    s[0] = '\0';
}
void string::operator=(const char* source)
{
    if (source == nullptr) {
        s = new char[1];
        s[0] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        size = strlen(source) + 1;
        s = new char[size];
        for (int k = 1; k < (strlen(source) + 1); k++) {
            s[k] = source[k];
        }
    }
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, string& result)
{
    output << result.s;
    return output;
}
```

And here is my main file which I tried to comply:

```
#include "custom_string.h"
int main()
{
    string a;
    a = "testfile";
    std::cout << a;
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

As you can see, I have declared a constructor to convert `const char` to my `custom string` by overloading assignment operator. However, there should be something wrong in my code and I could not find out it. Please help me and thank you

Comment: A good first step would be to name your class something else. There is no such error [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fbe16021fccfd57).

Comment: 1) What does "_However, when I debugged my code, the system said that:_" mean? You can only debug code, after you compile it. However "_no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char" to "string"_" Sounds like a compilation error. Which doesn't even match the code code you are showing. Since you are not using a constructor, that takes parameter, and are assigning `const char*`, and not `const char`. Additionally: it doesn't produce any compilation errors [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LjVdcaHmwPHxNDVk). You don't get any output, though, because `s[0]` is uninitialized.

Comment: Overloading assignment does not declare a constructor. Your only constructor is `string()`. Construction and assignment are very different things.

Comment: also no error without the rename, only one include was missing: https://godbolt.org/z/TxPan18bf. you don't have a `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code, do you?

Comment: Also, identifiers starting with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: `delete s;` is wrong, it should be `delete[] s;`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I mean I failed in comply my code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I have done to fix it. As it turned out, I have to declare one more constructor to covert between my `custom string` and `const char`. That is something like this:

> string::string(const string& t){}

> string& string::operator=(const char&source){}